# excluding facet field in solr

Tags: solr, faceted-search

Its a badly inserted data in solr which is the issue but is there way to fix the below scenerio.

```
"Attributes": [
      "Width=680 mm",
      "Height=990 mm",
      "Type=Recycling",
      "Color=White"
      "Size= L"

    ]
```

At front-end, all of the above fields are grouped according to key of the attribute , user can select any one of them.

There would be no issue at all if the above data would have been inserted as separate fields against a document(i can not change that). I could have easily exclude the facet field to show the count of the other related attribute. For example when user select Size L, i could show the result for XL and S.

But with this above data, its not possible to exclude correctly in case user select 'Color' and 'Size' at the same time.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved through tagging and excluding. You tag a filter and exclude them while building the facet counts. In your case

```
select?q=*:*&fq={!tag=pr}size:L&facet=on&facet.field={!ex=pr}size
```

You can do it for multiple facets too. Hope this helps.

Comment: I know how tagging and excluding works but problem is i only want to exclude part of a facet.field. Because in my solr instance  there is only one face.field with multi values as i have shown above but that facet.field is divided into multiple facets at front-end.